# How can I "hide" a column in my inner query?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery, dateadd

I am just started to learn the SQL so maybe the answer to my question is easy but I could not find out the solution without some help.
I have an SQL code that does not work:

```
select Case.ID from Case
where Case.ID not in 
(select distinct Case.ID, dateadd(year,1,Transaction.Date as DateAdd) 
from Transaction
join Case on Case.ID = Transaction.CaseID
where DateAdd > '2022.01.15')
```

If I run the inner query independently, the results will look like this:

```
| CaseID |   DateAdd   |
| -------| ------------|
| 1      | 2022-01-01  |
| 2      | 2022-02-01  |
| 3      | 2022-01-01  |
| 4      | 2022-02-01  |
```

I know that my query would work if I use only one column in my inner query for example:

```
select Case.ID from Case
where Case.ID not in 
(select distinct Case.ID
from Transaction
join Case on Case.ID = Transaction.CaseID)
```

Unfortunatly I need the `DateAdd` column, because I have to use a `WHERE` condition.
How can I solve that the `DateAdd` field would not be visible in the inner query?

Thank you for the help!

Comment: `where Case.ID not in (select distinct Case.ID, dateadd(year,1,Transaction.Date as DateAdd)...` you're comparing a list of Case.ID values (single column) to `not in` a 2-column list. Don't do that.

Comment: You don't need to include the `DateAdd` column in the select list. Just compute the value in the `WHERE` clause to filter out rows.

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? `dateadd` is a SQL-Server function, the MySQL function is `DATE_ADD`, and it has different syntax.

Answer (score 1):

The condition on the date should be in the subquery, not the main query. You don't need to select that column to use it in the condition.

```
select Case.ID 
from Case
where Case.ID not in (
    select distinct Transaction.CaseID
    FROM Transaction
    WHERE dateadd(Transaction.Date, INTERVAL 1 YEAR) > '2022-01-15'
)
```